# How to list all colors in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I would like to list all colors which are located in the class `Color.<color>`.

Where I can find all colors listed?

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion there is no native way to obtain that. I just check [the Color API](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html) and seems there isn't any function that gives you the default colors. But you can get them obtaining all the fields through reflection. Here I show you a sample:

```
private static List<Color> allColors() throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException {
    List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<>();
    Class clazz = Class.forName("javafx.scene.paint.Color");
    if (clazz != null) {
        Field[] field = clazz.getFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            Field f = field[i];                
            Object obj = f.get(null);
            if(obj instanceof Color){
                colors.add((Color) obj);
            }

        }
    }
    return colors;
}
```

Also if you want the name of the color you could retrieve it from the Field information in the moment of the extraction. And for example you can return a map with the information of the name and the color as shown above:

```
private static Map<String, Color> allColorsWithName() throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException {
    Map<String, Color> map = new HashMap<>();
    Class clazz = Class.forName("javafx.scene.paint.Color");
    if (clazz != null) {
        Field[] field = clazz.getFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            Field f = field[i];                
            Object obj = f.get(null);
            if(obj instanceof Color){
                map.put(f.getName(), (Color) obj);
            }

        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot.  BTW, this is the equivalent in Clojure:

    (def color-fields (.getFields (class Color/BLUE)))
    (def color-vals (map #(. % get nil) color-fields))
    (def color-names (map #(. % getName ) color-fields))
    (def color-map (zipmap color-names color-vals))